# Video show on the top off interstitial ads

Tags: admob, ads, policy, interstitial

I need some clarification on one thing.

I created an app for a videoplayer. My issue is that my video plays while "Interstitials" or "App Open" ads are playing.

Does this violate the AdMob regulation or not?

[image]

I have searched for this information but could not find a result.

Comment: Why not use `FullScreenContentCallback`s to play/pause your video when the Ads are shown / dismissed?

Answer (score 0):

This is a violation of google ad policy:

https://support.google.com/publisherpolicies/answer/11191353?hl=en

> Publishers should avoid site layouts in which the content fully or partially obscures Google ads. These layouts make it hard for users to distinguish between the content and ads.
>
> ....
>
> We suggest you avoid using wrapped floating text, as these layouts make it hard for users to distinguish between the content and ads and
> can cause content to obscure ads.

Comment: Thank you for your feed back but this is not exactly I ask according to these policy's when content fixed on ads this is violation but I my case it's moveable on whole screen  and also user allow permission for to do that

Comment: "Publishers should avoid site layouts in which the content fully or partially obscures Google ads". Your video does that, just because you can move it around doesn't avoid the fact that it's still always obscuring some part of the ad.

Comment: someone is trying to get his account banned.